# Использование данных SQLite для построения графика

Tags: android, файлы, sqlite, график

Хотелось бы проконсультироваться по следующему вопросу: в активности приложения необходимо построить график. Одной осью будет какое-то количество товара,  а другой дата. Для хранения количества и дат планировал использовать базу данных SQLite, потому что, как мне кажется, эти данные будет легче обрабатывать. Или не стоит так заморачиваться и использовать обычный файл? Только как тогда обрабатывать дату,если она будет храниться в виде дд.мм.гггг

Comment: да использовать базу данных будет намного удобнее и правильнее. заморачиваться с большей вероятностью придется именно с чтением файла, парсингом и вот этим вот всем

Comment: Мухи должны быть отделены от котлет. Данные должны быть отделены от их представления. Есть слой доступа к данным: он может брать их из БД, из файла, получать по сети...  Есть слой отображения: он может выводить данные в виде графика, диаграммы, таблицы... Одно никак не зависит от другого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

однозначно SQLlite, много удобных функций для работы с данными, есть индексы для больших объемов данных, механизм транзакций.  Selectы какие хочешь можно делать. Графики строить одно удовольствие.

Но работать с файлами все равно придется для бэкапа и обмена данными. Используй бинарный формат, он быстрее и  проще в загрузке.